# Reading in a CSV: 'Str Object Is Not an Iterator'

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, csv

I am attempting to read in a csv file and analyze some data. However, it appears I am missing a step with the csv import because I cannot iterate over the rows in the csv data. I am using Python 3.7. Below is my code:

```
import csv

bank_csv_path = os.path.join("Bank/Resources/budget_data.csv")

total_months = 0
net_total = 0
avg_total = []
greatest_increase = 0
greatest_decrease = 0

with open(bank_csv_path, newline="") as csvfile:
    bank = csvfile.read()
    next(bank)
```

Here is the TypeError I am recieving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bank.py", line 14, in <module>
    next(bank)
TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator
(base) Grants-MBP-2:python-challenge grant$
```

I should add that with the next function, I am trying to skip over the header row.

I am still learning the language so please let me know if I should include more information with my question, and I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

The python variable `next()` is an iterator that iterates over a specific kind of data type. Right now, your variable `bank` is a data type `str`. Therefore, you can't call `next(str)` and that is why you have the error output. Instead, try using a for loop to read row by row.

```py
with open('file.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_read = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        print(row)
```

Also, you can look into pandas which has a lot of goodies. The equivalent would be:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(file)
print(data)
```

Each of your columns would be your data and you can access it like: 
`data['col_name'].max()`

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you are using your `import csv` to begin with.

It also looks like you are reading your file directly via `open`, which means that if you want to skip your first line, you could instead use:

```
with open(bank_csv_path, newline="") as csvfile:
    bank = csvfile.readlines()
    bank = bank[1:]
```

This will remove the first line

A sample of your csv file format is further needed because we aren't sure what delimiters it is using.

For better manipulation of csv files, I would recommend using `pandas` instead.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not even using the `csv` module. Here the proper way to do what you want:

```
import csv

bank_csv_path = os.path.join("Bank/Resources/budget_data.csv")

total_months = 0
net_total = 0
avg_total = []
greatest_increase = 0
greatest_decrease = 0

with open(bank_csv_path, newline="") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)  # Create a file reader.
    next(reader)  # Skip header.
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# use pandas to open csv files and slice and dice as you please

import pandas as pd

bank_csv_path = os.path.join("Bank/Resources/budget_data.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(bank_csv_path)
df.head()
print(df)
df.shape
print(df.size)
print(len(df)) #prints data frame (df) length
print(df.columns) #prints column headers
print(df['column 1'])
#slicing data
print(df["column 2"][:4]) #prints everything in column 2 starting at index 3
print(df["column 2"][4]) #prints index 4 on column 2
```